# MongoDB: filter by array size and total with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using *aggregate* query.
I need to return a document if:

- "total" doesn't exist
- array size is lower then "total"

So hide all document that have ALL array *equal* to "total".

Notes:

- "container" can have different "subContainer"
- "subContainer" is a dynamic key name
- "total" is optional
- "arr" size <= "total"

Documents in collection:

```
[
  {  // "container.subContainer2.arr" is lower then "total"
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "title1",
    "container": {
      "subContainer1": {
        "arr": [1, 2, 3]
      },
      "subContainer2": {
        "arr": [1]
      }
    },
    "total": 3
  },
  {  // "total" unknow
    "_id": 2,
    "title": "title2",
    "container": {
      "subContainer3": {
        "arr": [1, 2, 3, 4]
      }
    }
  },
  {  // both array size are equal to "total"
    "_id": 3,
    "title": "title3",
    "container": {
      "subContainer4": {
        "arr": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      },
      "subContainer5": {
        "arr": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      }
    },
    "total": 5
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "title": "title1"
  },
  {
    "title": "title2"
  }
]
```

Comment: What array size should be lower then "total"? Any of the `subContainer` or all of the `subContainer` sizes?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic The size is related only to "arr" array.

Comment: But each `subContainer` has one `arr` array. Should all of them be lower that `total` or at least one?

Comment: Yes, each `subContainer` has at least one `arr` array. All of them can be _lower_ or _equal_ `total`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using `$not` to check if `total` exists (falsy) and `$cond` to check the result.

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        "$objectToArray": "$container"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField1": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$newField",
          "as": "z",
          "in": {
            "$size": "$$z.v.arr"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        "$min": "$newField1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "status": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$not": [
              "$total"
            ]
          },
          true,
          {
            "$gt": [
              "$total",
              "$newField"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "title": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/qrSiAX88UFZ

Answer (score 1):

first we add some extra field with `$addFields`
and with map create array that contains `arr`
and `sum` size of `arr` in each doc and put as newField
create status Field as boolean if `"arr" size <= "total"`
and `match` all doc with status : true and project title

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        "$objectToArray": "$container"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField1": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$newField",
          "as": "z",
          "in": {
            $size: "$$z.v.arr"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        "$sum": "$newField1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "status": {
        $gte: [
          "$total",
          "$newField"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      status: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/PhkeJUCkE6d

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I changed `$sum` with `$min` and `$gte` with `$gt` because I want return a document only if `arr` array size is lower then `total`.
It doesn't return any document when `total` is missing.

Comment: Could you fix problem?

Comment: I think you need sum of arr size and should be lt of total

Comment: `total` is like the limit to size of each `arr` array.

Comment: ok , if my answer help you to love problem , appreciate to make up vote :)